# How to get double request name to array in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Result from MODAL:

[image: Result from MODAL]

Result from FORM:

[image: Result from FORM]

#### DESCRIPTION:

So I wanna make a FORM from MODAL that will send data to actual FORM's table, but at the first **IMAGE** that not send like the FORM one.

#### CODE:

This is code from FORM attribute:

```
public function setLandCertificateIdAttribute($values)
{
    // dd($values);
    $this->attributes['land_certificate_id'] = implode(',', $values);
}
```

This is code using MODAL:

```
public function form(Model $model)
{
    $this->multipleSelect('land_certificate_id', 'Nomor Sertifikat')
        ->options(LandCertificate::where('data_order_id', $model->id)->pluck('number', 'id'));
}
```

And the MODAL always return : `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

*I'm using laravel-admin project btw*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implode(): Invalid arguments passed: It means that the function is expecting an array of data. 
The implode function in PHP is easily remembered as "**array to string**"

In your modal html set your land_certificate_id name as array.

For example.

```
<input type="text" name="land_certificate_id[]"></input>
```

Comment: I just changed `$this->multipleSelect('land_certificate_id[]', 'Nomor Sertifikat')
        ->options(LandCertificate::where('data_order_id', $model->id)->pluck('number', 'id'));
}`
and it works, thanks for your answer